# Making sense of HTTP code returned by CURL in PHP and validating URLs

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to make a small PHP program that will have an HTML form in which a user will enter a URL and click submit. I was trying to get the returned HTTP code from the URL via CURL. I gather that a return value of 0 is given in two situations: 1) when the domain exists but you can't connect to the server. The server refuses the connection. 2) When the host does not exist

My question is, how can I be sure about either of these two cases when I get an HTTP code equal to 0?

Better still, what should be my logic to make sure that the URL given  by the user is not only well-formed but also belongs to a valid website existing on the internet?

My code is below:

```
        $html_brand = "www.google.com/ihhhkhkj";
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            //CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ( $httpCode == 404 ){
            echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
                .curl_error($ch);

            $this->form_validation->set_message("url_check", "URL is well-formed but still not valid!");

            return FALSE;

        }
        else if($httpCode == 0)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message("url_check", "Could not connect to the URL given! Connection timed out!");

            //is it a server timeout or non-existent site?

            return FALSE;
        }

        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: Using [`gethostbyname($domain)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) you should at least be able to figure out if it's a domain issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP code is 0, you could use [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to figure out what the problem was with the `curl_exec` call.